# Getting 'argument type mismatch' error while passing values from a dataprovider class in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing 'argument type mismatch' error while trying to pass few values from the excel sheet using @dataprovider class to few methods in page objects class. In turn these methods are called in @test class. Can you please help me on this issue. The code has been mentioned below.

DataProvider

```html
@DataProvider(name="ProductInfo")
  public static Object[][] productInfoDataprovider() throws Throwable {
    
   File file = new File("C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/QAToolsECommerce/ECommerce_Data.xlsx");
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
   int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
   Object[][] obj = new Object[lastRowNum][5];
   for(int i=0; i<lastRowNum; i++){
    
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i+1);
    obj[i][0]= row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
    obj[i][1]= row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    obj[i][2]= row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
    obj[i][3]= row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
    obj[i][4]= row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
   }
  fis.close();
   return obj;
  }
```

PageObjects

```html
public class QaToolsECommercePageObjects {
 
 WebDriver driver;
 
 /*Method to launch the browser and select the browser type */
 public void setBrowser(int browser){
  
  if(browser == '1'){
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }else if(browser == '2'){
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
  }else if(browser == '3'){
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  }
  //Maximize the window
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
  //driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/");
  
  //browser load time
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }



 
 /* Searches the product required to purchase */
 public void searchProduct(String product){
  
  driver.findElement(By.name("s")).sendKeys(product);
  driver.findElement(By.name("s")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category")).click(); 
 }
 

 
 /* Verifies the product name in the product search result and adds the product to the cart*/
 public void productVerify(String product){
  
  String productValue = driver.findElement(By.id("grid_view_products_page_container")).getText();
  boolean val = productValue.contains(product); //Value from excel sheet
  if(val == true){
   
   System.out.println("The product searched is found :" +productValue);
   //Click on add to cart  
   driver.findElement(By.name("Buy")).click();
   //Click on Go to check out
   driver.findElement(By.className("go_to_checkout")).click(); 
  }else
  {
   System.out.println(" The product searched is not found :" +productValue);
  }
  
 }
 
 
 /* Verifies the product name, quantity, price and total price of the product */
 
 public void checkoutCartVerify(String product, int quantity, String prices, String totalPrices){
  
  WebElement cartTable = driver.findElement(By.className("checkout_cart"));
  List<WebElement> cartRows = cartTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  
  //Product name
  WebElement prodRow = cartRows.get(1);
  List<WebElement> prodCols = prodRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
  WebElement prodName = prodCols.get(1);
  String oriProdName = prodName.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText();
  
  //Comparing product name 
  if(oriProdName.equals(product)){
   System.out.println("The Product searched and added to the cart is correct: "+oriProdName);
  }else
  {
   System.out.println("The product searched and added to the cart is incorrect: "+oriProdName);
  }
  
  
  //Quantity
  WebElement quantityCombo = prodCols.get(2).findElement(By.tagName("form"));
  List<WebElement> quantityVals = quantityCombo.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
  String prodQuantity = quantityVals.get(0).getAttribute("value");
  int pq = Integer.parseInt(prodQuantity);
  //Comparing product quantity 
  if(pq == quantity){
   System.out.println("The Product quantity added to the cart is correct: "+pq);
  }else
  {
   System.out.println("The product quantity added to the cart is incorrect: "+pq);
  }
  
  //Price
  String price = prodCols.get(3).getText();
  String[] priceSplit = price.split("\\.");
  String prodPrice = priceSplit[0];
  String priceFrac = priceSplit[1];
  System.out.println(price);
  
  
  //Comparing price of the quantity 
  if(priceFrac.equals("00")){
   if(prodPrice.equals(prices)){
    System.out.println("The Product price added to the cart is correct: "+prodPrice);
   }else{
    System.out.println("The product price added to the cart is incorrect: "+prodPrice);
   }
   
  }else
  {
   if(price.equals(prices)){
    System.out.println("The Product price added to the cart is correct: "+price);
   }else{
    System.out.println("The product price added to the cart is incorrect: "+price);
   }
   
  }
  
  //Total Price
  String totalPrice = prodCols.get(4).getText();
  String[] totalpriceSplit = totalPrice.split("\\.");
  String prodTotalprice = totalpriceSplit[0];
  String prodpriceFrac = totalpriceSplit[1];
  System.out.println(totalPrice);
  
  //Comparing Total Price of the quantity
  if(prodpriceFrac.equals("00")){
   if(prodTotalprice.equals(totalPrices)){
    System.out.println("The Product Total price added to the cart is correct: "+prodTotalprice);
   }else{
    System.out.println("The product Total price added to the cart is incorrect: "+prodTotalprice);
   }
  }else
  {
   if(totalPrice.equals(totalPrices)){
    System.out.println("The Product Total price added to the cart is correct: "+totalPrice);
   }else{
    System.out.println("The product Total price added to the cart is incorrect: "+totalPrice);
   }
  }
  
 }
```

Test Class

```html
public class QaToolsECommerceTest {
  @Test(dataProvider = "ProductInfo", dataProviderClass = QaToolsECommerceDataProvider.class)
  
  public void eCommerceProduct(int browser, String product, int quantity, String prices, String totalPrices) {
   QaToolsECommercePageObjects qaEpo = new QaToolsECommercePageObjects();
   
   qaEpo.setBrowser(browser);
   qaEpo.searchProduct(product);
   qaEpo.productVerify(product);
   qaEpo.checkoutCartVerify(product, quantity, prices, totalPrices);

  }

}
```

Error:

> FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2.0, "Magic Mouse", 1.0, "$150", "$150")
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2.0, "Magic Mouse", 1.0, "$150", "$150")
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Actually in method `eCommerceProduct()` you are expecting arguments are as `int`, `String`, `int`, `String`, `String` while actual arguments are passing as `double`, `String`, `double`, `String`, `String`.

So you should change the method `eCommerceProduct()` with expecting arguments as :-

```
public void eCommerceProduct(double browser, String product, double quantity, String prices, String totalPrices) {
   -------
   -------
}
```

**Edited** :-

> Running: C:\Users\chetan.k.thimmanna\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclips‌​e--1620381105\testng‌​-customsuite.xml 1 FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2, "Magic Mouse", 1, "$150", "$150") java.lang.NullPointerException at qaToolsECommerceExcel.QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser‌​(QaToolsECommercePag‌​eObjects.java:42)

This error occurred because you are calling `QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser(browser);` inside `eCommerceProduct()` method with passing `browser` value into `int` or `double` while in `QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser(int browser)` method you are comparing it as  `if(browser == '1')` means in string which is wrong.

You should modify your `QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser(int browser)` method as below :-

```
public class QaToolsECommercePageObjects {

  WebDriver driver;

  public void setBrowser(int browser){
        WebDriver driver
        if(browser == 1){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }else if(browser == 2){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }else if(browser == 3){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/chetan.k.thimmanna/Documents/Selenium/Resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        //Maximize the window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
        //driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/");

        //browser load time
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
 -----
 -----
}
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, the older error resolved. But now i'm getting 'FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2, "Magic Mouse", 1, "$150", "$150") java.lang.NullPointerException'. In excel sheet i have only one row of values, Is this error because of that ? Kindly help me.

Comment: Could you share full stacktrace??

Comment: [TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\chetan.k.thimmanna\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1620381105\testng-customsuite.xml

1
FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2, "Magic Mouse", 1, "$150", "$150")
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at qaToolsECommerceExcel.QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser(QaToolsECommercePageObjects.java:42)
 at qaToolsECommerceExcel.QaToolsECommerceTest.eCommerceProduct(QaToolsECommerceTest.java:13)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)

 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)

Comment: at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)

Comment: at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

Comment: @Chetan_K See updated answer there is a mistake in your `QaToolsECommercePageObjects.setBrowser()` method, needs to fix it, you shoud compare with `browser` value as `if(browser == 1)`, try with updated answer ans let me know..:)

Comment: Thank you very much, now its working as expected. Appreciate the help  :)

Answer (score 1):

In your dataprovider function productInfoDataprovider(), you have

```
  obj[i][0]= row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
  obj[i][2]= row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
```

getNumericCellValue() has return parameter as double due to which you're getting argument type mismatch.

Type cast it to int by using

```
  obj[i][0]= (int)row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
  obj[i][2]= (int)row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, the older error resolved. But now i'm getting                'FAILED: eCommerceProduct(2, "Magic Mouse", 1, "$150", "$150")
java.lang.NullPointerException'. In excel sheet i have only one row of values, Is this error because of that ? Kindly help me.

Comment: None of your 'if else if' condition is getting passed as you are checking equality with '1' ,'2', '3' (string values). Due to this, driver object is not initialised. Thus, NullpointerException is thrown for driver object. Please change the values to 1,2,3 and also add another else {} to show error message or open any default web driver.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, now its working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are initiating the browser, you wrote "else if(browser == '2')". Here you are expecting 2 as character but you are proving data as int/Double. Try

```
else if(browser == 2 )
```

Before that, cast the double value of browser variable to integer.